# How to integrate $\frac{1}{(x^3-a^3)^3}$ for a few limits

Tags: integration

I need to integrate this:

$$
\int\frac{1}{(x^3-a^3)^3}\mathrm{d}x
$$

For a few limits: $(-a, \infty)$ and for $[0,\infty)$. Just to clarify:

$$
\int_{-a + \varepsilon}^{\infty} \text{and} \int_{0}^{\infty}
$$

**PS:** $a<0$ and $\varepsilon$ is small.

Comment: For one, you could use [partial fractional decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). You should also specify $a>0$ I guess.

Comment: @TroyWoo Thanks, forget about $a$, actually it's less than zero, so $-a+\varepsilon$ is positive and a bit greater than $a$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer to formulate this with $1/(x^3+a^3)^3$ and assume $a>0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a<0$, your second integral becomes $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{dx}{\Big(x^3+b^3\Big)^3}$ , which, by letting $x=b~t$, followed

by $u=\dfrac1{t^3+1}$ , becomes a multiple of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) of arguments $\dfrac13$ and $\dfrac23$ . Then, employing

Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties), we arrive at the desired result, $I=\dfrac{10~\pi}{27\sqrt3\cdot b^8}$. **ALL**

integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{p-1}}{\Big(x^n+b^n\Big)^m}~dx$ can be solved using this approach, yielding the general

formula $I=\dfrac{B\bigg(m-\dfrac pn~,~\dfrac pn\bigg)}{n~b^{mn-p}}$, which, as I said above, can be simplified using Euler's reflection

formula.

Comment: Why didn't I notice this by myself? That's an awesome and easy way to do this!